# Await value returned from a redux-thunk dispatch rather than using state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using react, redux, and redux-thunk have a set of queries I have to run in the "logic layer".  The results of each "action" call determine the path I take, so I am actually awaiting the promises returned from the dispatch call to the redux-thunks.

```
const handleClick = async (args) => {
  let foo = await dispatch(fetchFoo(args));
  if(foo) { do something... }
  else {
    let bar = await dispatch(fetchBar(args));
    if(bar) { do another thing... }
    else { or do another thing... }
   }
};
```

Example thunk:

```
export const fetchFoo = args => async (dispatch) => {
  let foo = await api.fetchFoo(args);
  dispatch(fetchSuccess(foo));
  // !!!!!!!!!!
  return foo;
  // !!!!!!!!!!
}
```

If I don't do this, it's pretty awkward to wait until a re-render (maybe) puts "foo" in the redux state prop, then wait again until a re-render (maybe) puts "bar" in the redux state, etc...

I've never really seen this pattern before although I have seen awaiting void promises return from thunks.

Is it acceptable to return the value from the redux-thunk action and use it rather than getting the values from a redux state selector?  This seems to break the rules of the "single source of truth."  If not, what do I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this approach it would be much harder to refactor state and change flow how data is loaded. Say in case requirements are changed and `fetchBar()` should be called by interval or need to be loaded by parent and passed through props. Or you want to throttle loading. Or cache data for some time.

I used this pattern with `Promise` returned and found it makes things rather complicated. The only advantage I found: I didn't need having `isLoading` or `loadingError` flags in redux storage to know if data is already loaded or not.

But also it means I have to call some methods redundantly just to retrieve brand new `Promise` await for - since promises can be resolved only once - in order to wait until some data loaded. And once some action triggers few API calls in sequence I ended with awaiting for data I did not even need.

In opposite if we rely only on data in `redux` it would be as easy as `const isStillLoading = props.isData1Loading && props.isData2Loading`

Consider moving condition for loading data into action itself. If you find API calls sequence becomes too complex you may switch to [`redux-saga`](https://flaviocopes.com/redux-saga/) or [`redux-loop`](https://lorefnon.tech/2018/02/04/redux-loop-a-better-solution-for-managing-asynchronous-operations-in-redux/) which both provide better control over execution flow.

Comment: I have to read this a few more times to make sure I understand. For a little background, I am browsing thousands of records, then click on one which loads a detail window that needs foo or bar. I could load in the detail window, but I like how simple it is now.

Comment: maybe in this particular case there is no benefit in using `redux` for storing context-specific data, what do you think?

Comment: yes I had that thought, I was just trying to keep the api out of my components.